# How much energy is needed to convert 20.0 grams of water at 15.0 degrees C to steam at 100.0 degrees C?

Tags: water, energy, phase

How much energy is needed to convert 20.0 grams of water at 15.0 degrees C to steam at 100.0 degrees C?

Comment: Show your work.

Answer (score 1):

Enthalpy of vaporization of water: [$40.65\pu{\frac {kJ}{mol}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_vaporization). This is the amount of energy to convert one mole of water at boiling point to gas.

One calorie = [$4.184$ $\pu{J}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorie) = Energy required to raise the temperature of one gram of water one degree Celsius.

Molar mass of water: [$18.01528\pu{\frac{g}{mol}}$](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/water). This is the mass of one mole of water.

That being said, $\pu{E_{Total}}$ = $\pu{E_{h}}$ + $\pu{E_{v}}$, where $\pu{E_{h}}$ is the energy used in heating it and $\pu{E_{v}}$ is the energy used to vaporize it. $\pu{E_{h}} = 4.184$ $\pu{\frac{J}{cal}}$ $\times$ $20$ $\pu{g}$ $\times$ $85$ $\pu{°C} \approx 7112$ $\pu{J}$. $\pu{E_{v}}$ = $40.65\pu{\frac {kJ}{mol}}$ $\times$ $20$ $\pu{g}$ $\times$ $1000\pu{\frac{J}{kJ}}$ divided by $18.01528\pu{\frac{g}{mol}} \approx 4513$ (significant figures). $7112 + 45130 = 52242$ $\pu{J}$.

Comment: Good answer, but it would be preferable if you didn't give a complete answer. We don't like to show ourselves as a homework completion site.